# Using the method initWithData:error: in order to play audio from memory buffer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create an application for the iPhone that plays a custom memory buffer.
I am currently using AVAudioPlayer class and I am pretty sure that the function I should use is "initWithData:error:".

The problem is that I don't know which kind of data I have to pass as an argument, and reading the poor API doesn't help me much.

Can someone please help me or send me an example of a working input?

Thanks for helping!

Sagiftw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an NSData object.

Make that data object like this: `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: @"The song file name.type"]`

Comment: Oh, and BTW, the APIs are very good, you just need to learn to read them.